# JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation in SP_PROCEDURE

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing Simple JavaScript Based Procedure in Snowflake and getting weird error

While calling this procedure i am getting following error,

JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation in SP_PROCEDURE at ' var ret=Delete();

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_PROCEDURE"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
AS $$ 
        
         
         function Delete()         
           {        
                    var DeleteRepositoryTable=`DELETE FROM "TABLEA"`;
                    
                     try{
                                                        
                            
                     snowflake.execute({sqlText:DeleteRepositoryTable});

                       return "Success";
                     }
                     
                     catch(err)
                     {return "Error Ocurred While Loading Data" + err;  }
            }
            
            
            
            
        var ret=Delete();  ------------ 

        return ret;


        
        $$
```

Comment: For a start, your Delete function is not returning anything if it doesn’t error

Comment: @NickW , no Sir, still same problem, I modified my code to return the message

Comment: Is "------------ " part of your original SP DDL, or just to indicate to us it is the line that has the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure works fine for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_PROCEDURE"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
AS $$ 
         
         function Delete()         
           {        
                    var DeleteRepositoryTable=`DELETE FROM "CITIBIKE_TRIPS_TEMP"`;              
                     try{                                      
                         snowflake.execute({sqlText:DeleteRepositoryTable});
                         return "Success";
                     } catch(err) { 
                         return "Error Ocurred While Loading Data" + err;  
                     }
            }
        var ret=Delete();
        return ret;
        $$;
```

When I call it:

```
CALL "SP_PROCEDURE"();
```

I get back **Success**.
How are you calling the procedure?